# Most efficient / Best way to call a javascript method contained within an object - by string

Tags: javascript, function, callback, eval

Alright - here's the story:

I have a form definition:

```
<form method="post" data-callback="OBJECT[callback]">
```

There is also a global living object called: OBJECT which has a method callback();

What is the best method of parsing the string in "data-callback", converting it to a function name (but it can be an object - like now - not a global function) and calling it WITH specific params, applied from a specific context? :)

Thanks!

Comment: So is OBJECT in global scope?

Comment: So this always begins with `OBJECT`? Then leave that out and put only `callback` there (or parse it out), and use the method name (string) with bracket notation.

Comment: Yes - it's in global scope - but this is just a custom case scenario for the moment. It can be in ANY scope.